# It seems I have a virus

Tags: 16.04, redirect

In the Chrome browser it redirects to npmpecd.com/rcp with a very light v at the end of the string.  Under the address on the top of that page there is a sort of banner which says: Brought to you by Lyrics    .
  I was trying to put a micro kernel (Helen) into qemu and the instructions asked to turn off pkg mgr  and in the process I got fouled up.  In the time I have been using Ubuntu virus' have not been a bother.
  Part of me feels it would be easier to just get the dvd out and reload the O/S but a part of me is curious to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct if a system has had the malicious code running on it overall it's now compromised and needs to be wiped. It's possible for malware to live beyond a single install, but not very likely.

You can also run `debsums` to validate the package integrity. It's possible for an attacker to add himself to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and similar files so that these signatures are "valid" but unlikely.

Otherwise the code can also be included as a binary "override" somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/gnome-login-manager` or similar allowing them to inject their code when that program is used.

A kernel module could also have been installed which does the malware. Can also be a chrome extension.